# Is there a way to predetermine the size of text in a wx.StaticText?

Tags: wxpython

The project I'm working on involves creating a group of panels, some with a StaticText object in them, and I want to predetermine how large the text will be so that I can determine a) how large to make the panels containing the text and b) how much space is left for the other panels.

It's probably important to note that I am doing sizing and placement manually, and not using any kind of wx.Sizer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wx.Font` rides to the rescue!
If you're not using sizers, you become responsible for the `size` of the widgets.
Simply, adjust the `font` for the appropriate Static texts and approximate their sizes.

```
import wx 
 
class Mywin(wx.Frame): 
    def __init__(self, parent, title): 
        super(Mywin, self).__init__(parent, title = title,size = (700,500))
        panel = wx.Panel(self) 
        box = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL) 
        lbl0 = wx.StaticText(panel,-1, pos=(10,10)) 
        lbl1 = wx.StaticText(panel,-1, pos=(10,100)) 
        lbl2 = wx.StaticText(panel,-1, pos=(10,190)) 
        
        txt = "Python GUI development using wxPython" 
        
        font = wx.Font(16, wx.ROMAN, wx.ITALIC, wx.NORMAL) 
        lbl0.SetFont(font) #Set font and size for lbl
        lbl0.SetLabel(txt+' x16') 
        lbl0.SetSize((16*(len(txt)),30))
        lbl0.SetBackgroundColour('lightgreen') 
        
        lbl1.SetLabel(txt+' xNormal') #No font change for lbl1
        lbl1.SetBackgroundColour('lightblue') 
        
        font = self.GetFont() 
        font.SetPointSize(22) 
        lbl2.SetFont(font) #Set font size for lbl2
        lbl2.SetLabel(txt+' x22')       
        lbl2.SetSize((22*(len(txt)),34))   
        self.Show() 
        
app = wx.App()
Mywin(None,  'StaticText demo') 
app.MainLoop()
```

[image]